# Cassandra - java data modeling

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Trying my hands on cassandra for the first time. We are using datastax java-driver 4.14, and I am having issue in mapping the primary key to a separate java class. How do I define RKey in
RDAO.  I am getting errors while writting a has-a relationship with RDAO
.

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.14.1</version>
        </dependency>

public class RKey {

    @PartitionKey(0)
    @CqlName(value = "mart_id")
    public int martId;

    @PartitionKey(1)
    @CqlName(value = "product_id")
    public String productId;

    @PartitionKey(2)
    @CqlName(value = "store_id")
    public  String storeId;
}


@Entity
@CqlName("abc")
public class RDAO {

    RKey pk;
   
    @CqlName(value = "compressed_rollup_data")
    ByteBuffer compressedRollupData;
    @CqlName(value = "metadata")
    String metadata;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its not possible. We went ahead with inheritance which is supported